# POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I have a problem in the console "POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error) "
I think I can't reach the api when I login :

here is my login component in react :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Login.css'
import { Form, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BiLogIn } from 'react-icons/bi'
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {
    //const [user, setUser] = useState(null); 
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/api/login',
            {
                email,
                password,
            });

            // Afficher une alerte pour indiquer que la connexion a réussi
            alert(res.data.message);

            // Rediriger vers /books
            window.location.href = '/Books';
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };


    const login_font = new URL('../../assets/login-font.jpg', import.meta.url);
    return (

        <div>
            <img src={login_font} className='login-font' alt='' />
            <center>
                <span className='login'>
                    <h2><b><BiLogIn /> Login</b></h2> <br />
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGroupEmail">
                            <Form.Label><b>Email address</b></Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGroupPassword">
                            <Form.Label><b>Password</b></Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formHorizontalCheck">
                            <Col sm={{ span: 5, offset: 3 }}>
                                <Form.Check label="Remember me" />
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                            <Button type='submit' variant="primary" size="smx" >login</Button>
                        </div>
                        {error && (
                            <div className="text-danger mt-3">
                                Incorrect email or password. Please try again.
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Form>
                </span>
            </center>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Here is my api in express js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
app.use(express.json());

let refreshTokens = [];

const users = [
  {
    id: "1",
    username: "nacer",
    email: "user1@example.com",
    password: "password1",
    isAdmin: true,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    username: 'imane',
    email: 'user2@example.com',
    password: 'password2',
    isAdmin: false,
  },
];

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  //res.json("hey it works");
  const user = users.find(u => {
    return u.email === email && u.password === password;
  });
  if (user) {
    //Generate an access token
    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
    const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(user);
    refreshTokens.push(refreshToken);
    res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, { httpOnly: true });
    res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true });
    res.status(200).alert({
      message: 'Login successful! Thank you for joining us!'
    });

    res.redirect('/Books');
  } else {
    res.status(400).json('username or password incorrect! ')
  }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 5000');
});
```

react package.json :

```
{
  "name": "biblio-ensaf",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to redirect the user to the /Books page already created in react when his or her loging is correct

Comment: HTTP error 500 is a server error; are there any errors that show up on ther server?

Comment: i don't think so here is the terminal after running the server 'nodemon server.js'  :              [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server started on port 5000

Comment: Do not store passwords like that. Wow. It makes it look like you are going to attack your users and hijack their accounts, and even if you are perfectly innocent, it gives away everybody's logins to every attacker that finds an exploit. Store a salted hash and see that the provided password hashes to the same value when concatenated with their random salt.

Comment: You should be able to send all the authentication data to an attacker and say "Come at me, bro", and they still can't log in with any account that has a decent password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to send your request like so:

```
try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/login',
        {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        });

        // Afficher une alerte pour indiquer que la connexion a réussi
        alert(res.data.message);

        // Rediriger vers /books
        window.location.href = '/Books';
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```